How to get AWS Lambda queue size at runtime in Async Invocation?
I have a use case where I need to know the current size of queue in async invocation of AWS lambda, based on the queue size and few other data points my code has to decide how many more Lambda invocations to do.

What queue are you talking about? Are you referring to an SQS queue or something? The AWS Lambda service itself does not have queues, but it can be integrated with queue services such as SQS, Amazon MQ, etc.

@Mark B - In Async lambda invocation events is placed in queue and separate process delegates events from queue to lambda function. Take look at official document - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html

Lambda does not support this, you can only check number of invocations and errors of lambda in the cloud watch.
These are metrics provided by AWS
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-metrics.html
This is how you can check in cloudwatch.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-functions-access-metrics.html

If you are talking about this event queue in the docs BELOW, it is managed internally by Lambda Service. If you have available concurrent lambda according to your account limit, it will be executed soon.

invoke lambda async
code lambda to store/send result or generate any other event too.

docs for async lambda invocations
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html#invocation-dlq


Thanks for detailed comment. Yes, information is available via cloud watch but we wanted to get that information at runtime.

If you provide real scenario, I might be able to help, we have developed serverless apps at large scale for example video processing, we managed big flows using step functions and never found any requirement for getting to know these queue lengths.
Further lambda provide throttling and concurrency configuration and dead letter queue to manage or retry if any failed.
Please add real scenario why you need this, there might be another alternative to handle that.
